# Calculating the difference between each element against other randomly generated elements in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am calculating the difference of each element in a numpy array. My code is

```
import numpy as np

M = 10

x = np.random.uniform(0,1,M)

y = np.array([x])

# Calculate the difference

z = np.array(y[:,None]-y)
```

When I run my code I get `[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]`. I don't get a 10 by 10 array.

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for numpy

```
y.T - x
```

Another way:

```
np.subtract.outer(x, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting 10 by 10 array because value of M is 10. Try:

```
    M = (10,10)
```